# Avoid 'nothing known about [parent] class...' error in swig

Tags: interface, wrapper, swig

Let's say I have two classes A in header file A.h

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
  void foo();
};
```

and B in header file B.h

```
// B.h
class B : public A {
public:
  void bar()
};
```

I want to generate a Swig wrapper for class B. The interface file looks like this.

```
B.i
%{
#include "B.h"
%}

%include B.h
```

When running swig, it quits with an error message 'nothing known about A', which is clear, since B inherits from A and thus swig must know about A to generate the interface. Lets further assume there is some stuff in A.h the swig parser can not parse and it generates an error, when it sees that stuff. I suddenly decide, that I actually don't only need bar in the interface and not foo. Is there A way to tell swig, that it doesn't actually look at A.h, since I don't really need the stuff B inherits from A?

Answer (score 5):

You could use %import for the base class.  This lets SWIG know about the class, but no wrappers will be generated.  From the [SWIG 2.0 documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn20):

> If any base class is undefined, SWIG still generates correct type
>   relationships. For instance, a function accepting a Foo * will accept
>   any object derived from Foo regardless of whether or not SWIG actually
>   wrapped the Foo class. **If you really don't want to generate wrappers
>   for the base class, but you want to silence the warning, you might
>   consider using the %import directive to include the file that defines
>   Foo. %import simply gathers type information, but doesn't generate
>   wrappers.** Alternatively, you could just define Foo as an empty class
>   in the SWIG interface or use warning suppression.

Answer (score 4):

I threw together an example, and only get a *warning* that nothing is known about A.  The extension still builds fine and can call B's foo() without knowing about A's bar().  Here's my example generating a Python extension for Windows:

### Build output

```
C:\example>nmake /las
b.cpp
a.cpp
Generating Code...
   Creating library b.lib and object b.exp
B.h(12) : Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'A'. Ignored.
b_wrap.cxx
   Creating library _b.lib and object _b.exp
```

### Example use

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import b
>>> b.B().bar()
In B::bar()
>>> b.B().foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "b.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, B, name)
  File "b.py", line 54, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: foo
```

### Files

#### a.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLL_API A
{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

#### b.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "a.h"

class DLL_API B : public A
{
public:
    void bar();
};
```

#### a.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DLL_EXPORTS
#include "a.h"

void A::foo()
{
    printf("In A::foo()\n");
}
```

#### b.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DLL_EXPORTS
#include "b.h"

void B::bar()
{
    printf("In B::bar()\n");
}
```

#### b.i

```
%module b

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4100 4127 4706)
%}

%{
#include "B.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "B.h"
```

#### makefile

```
_b.pyd: b.dll b_wrap.cxx
    cl /nologo /EHsc /LD /W4 b_wrap.cxx /I c:\Python26\include /Fe_b.pyd -link /nologo /libpath:c:\Python26\libs b.lib

b_wrap.cxx: b.i
    swig -c++ -python b.i

b.dll: a.cpp b.cpp
    cl /nologo /LD /W4 b.cpp a.cpp
```