# A couple more SWIG warnings

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I am trying to create some ruby wrappers around a c++ library.
I have most of it working, but I have a few Warnings that I would like to fix.

The issues are with 2 header files, here are the snips of code

```
typedef std::set<WParm,std::less<WParm> > WParmlistType;
typedef WParmlistType::iterator  WParmlistIter;

class WParmlist : public WParmlistType {
```

and the warning I get ...
Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'WParmlistType'. Ignored.

and the second header is similar :

```
typedef std::vector<WString> WEditType;
typedef WEditType::iterator  WEditIter;

class WEdit : public WEditType {
```

with a similar warning:

Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'WEditType'. Ignored.

I had seen this type of warning before, but that was related to inheritance from std::string.  Those caused real problems in that I was unable to get the returned string values.  I was able to get past that by using %include std_string.i,  thanks to the answer found here : [swig Nothing known about base class 'std::string', ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602734/swig-nothing-known-about-base-class-stdstring-ignored) .  I was thinking there was some other directive I may need to handle the typedefs in this situation.

Comment: Add what you have tried. Your question doesn't show any effort.

Comment: Note sure what more I can add.  I ran swig on an interface file that included headers that contain the above code and I get those warnings. which I really don't understand how to fix. Here is a link to a related question that I asked and was answered,  I would have continued the question there, but I felt it was a separate issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602734/swig-nothing-known-about-base-class-stdstring-ignored/20603428?noredirect=1#20603428

Comment: Well, nothing indicates that you have looked at the SWIG docs or done a web search or searched on SO for questions like yours.

Comment: yes,  I actually did spend a bunch of time reading the swig doc and searching,  I guess I was just to excited to start playing with this in ruby,  and did not put in enough details in my question.  At first I thought this whole endeavor was over my head, but in the end it was pretty easy.  SWIG is pretty cool,  I will definitely be using it again!

Comment: I encourage you to edit your question to indicate what you have looked at in relation to that question, and to indicate why my answer did not answer your question, perhaps I can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a warning saying that you won't be able to instantiate WEditType or WParmlistType in ruby. You **will** be able to instantiate the **derived** classes WEdit and WParmList, just not the base classes. This matters only if you want to derived new classes from WEditType or WParmlistType **in ruby**. If not, you can just ignore the warning. Always take a look at the SWIG docs at http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/. For instance there is a good explanation of what I said at http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn20. Also, always do a search with google, especially look at results on SO. A search for the error message showed [Avoid 'nothing known about [parent] class...' error in swig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483614/avoid-nothing-known-about-parent-class-error-in-swig), which provides similar explanations.

Comment: I don't think I would need to instantiate WEditType or WParmlistType.  Looking thru the header file, what is shown above is the only usage of those types.

Answer (score 1):

When you use templates in SWIG, you can let SWIG know what templates you use so it can generate wrapper code for it.  In the case of `vector<WString>`, you can use:

```
%include <std_vector.i>
%template() std::vector<WString>;
```

Comment: This was a very helpful comment,  I found later several cases were I was not getting the proper return values back, and adding this for each of the similar occurrences solved my problem